# "She left small pins in the shoes he wore to injure his feet" – is this ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, syntactic-analysis

> She left small pins in all the shoes he wore to injure his feet.

I wrote this sentence and I thought it was fine. When I re-read it, the meaning became unclear to me. I want it to mean that she put pins in his shoes in order to cut his feet, but it also sounds like I mean she left pins in the shoes that he wore when he wanted to injure himself.

Am I completely over-thinking this sentence? Does my intended meaning come across?

Comment: This kind of syntactic ambiguity is most often encountered in news headlines, where it is called a [crash blossom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity#In_headlines_).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of good suggestions from Atkins, but you could also improve the clarity by removing the redundant "... he wore" which would immediately remove the confusion:

> She left small pins in all his shoes, to injure his feet.

Answer (score 1):

I gathered your intended interpretation on first reading, but your second meaning could also be taken. A comma would help:

> She left small pins in all the shoes he wore, to injure his feet.

But to be completely clear, reorder the sentence thus:

> To injure his feet, she left small pins in all the shoes he wore.

Comment: Ambiguity not totally removed. Try putting the 2nd part before the comma.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction True - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @atkins To me the comma looks out of place in your first example. I think the second sentence is the best.

Comment: @atkins: Nice. +1.

Comment: she tried to injure him by putting pins in all his shoes.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I was wondering, if I were to change the end of the sentence, would it make any clearer: She left small pins in all the shoes he wore to cause injury to his feet @marvmills